# Component doesn't work properly inside functional Component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've encountered a problem while using the `react-native-swipeable` component, normally it works fine but it seems if I try to use it from within a stateless functional component it stops working properly. I wonder if this is an issue with my code?

Both scenarios are called from a parent component like this:

```
render() {
    const {currentlyOpenSwipeable} = this.state;
    const itemProps = {
        onOpen: (event, gestureState, swipeable) => {
            if (currentlyOpenSwipeable && currentlyOpenSwipeable !== swipeable) {
                currentlyOpenSwipeable.recenter();
            }

            this.setState({currentlyOpenSwipeable: swipeable});
        },
        onClose: () => this.setState({currentlyOpenSwipeable: null})
    };
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.data}
                    renderItem={({item}) => (
                       <ListItem
                           {...itemProps}
                           item = {item}/>
                    )}
                    extraData={this.state}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.docId}/>
            </View>
       )
  }
```

Basically if I use this component directly in the render function it works great:

```
class ListItem extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.swipeable = null
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Swipeable onRef={ref => this.swipeable = ref}
                    rightButtons={[
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                            <Icon name="delete" size={24} color={'white'}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    ]}
                    onRightButtonsOpenRelease={this.props.onOpen}
                    onRightButtonsCloseRelease={this.props.onClose}>
                        <View>
                            <Text> Test </Text>
                        </View>
                </Swipeable>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

If I try to render it from within a functional component, it still swipes but it immediately closes, making it impossible to use.

```
class ListItem extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.swipeable = null
    }
    render(){
        const RenderSwipeRow = () => {
             return(
                <View>
                    <Swipeable onRef={ref => this.swipeable = ref}
                        rightButtons={[
                            <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                                <Icon name="delete" size={24} color={'white'}/>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        ]}
                        onRightButtonsOpenRelease={this.props.onOpen}
                        onRightButtonsCloseRelease={this.props.onClose}>
                            <View>
                                <Text> Test </Text>
                            </View>
                    </Swipeable>
                </View>
            )
        }

        return(
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <RenderSwipeRow/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I don't get what the difference is here. I was thinking that somehow I'm not passing all the required props to the component, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

If log this.state.currentlyOpenSwipeable at the parent level render, it shows that when the swipe works properly there is a `lastOffset` value and `rightButtonsOpen = true`

[image: proper swipe]

and when the swipe doesnt work (when rendered from the functional component) those fields look unset or incorrect:

[image]

So maybe the updated values for `this.state.currentlyOpenSwipeable` aren't being set?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are saying its a stateless functional component but are attempting to set and then use component state in your render which is a bad idea. If you want to keep it stateless you should find a way to pass that data as a prop or have the state be managed outside the render.

The render function should always be kept pure and you should be receiving console warnings for this.

Comment: I've moved the component from stateless functional to a stateful component class, had to pass all the state and props to it but it works now. Thanks